# What are csClickEvents and csCaptureMouse exactly?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm trying to understand the `ControlStyle` property in Delphi 2007, but I'm having trouble grasping the `csClickEvents` and `csCaptureMouse` attributes.

According to specifications, `csCaptureMouse` makes the control capture mouse events when it is clicked, whereas `csClickEvents` enables the control to receive and answer to mouse clicks. It also mentions explicitly that `TButton` does not inherit this attribute (I've checked the source code: this is indeed the case).

What exactly do `csCaptureMouse` and `csClickEvents` do, and what is the difference? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csCaptureMouse means for example that the component will receive MouseUp event (after click on the component) even if the mouse was released out of the component's bounds;

csClickEvents means that the component generates OnClick events.

These options are different.

---

About why TButton does not include csClickEvents - the answer is:

> Because the mechanism through which
>   you receive clicks for a TButton is
>   different - it generates click events
>   from a BN_CLICKED windows message,
>   which is the windows way of handling
>   buttons, rather than via
>   WML_BUTTONDOWN, which is the default
>   for a TControl.  It may be that now
>   you've included csClickEvents that
>   you'll get two Clicks for every mouse
>   click, or perhaps one will be
>   discarded, but you may still get
>   strange behaviour.  I haven't delved
>   deeply enough to know the pitfalls of
>   turning csClickEvents on but I
>   wouldn't assume it will be plain
>   sailing.

I have found this answer in [New Zealand DUG archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/delphi@delphi.org.nz/msg08774.html)

Comment: Thanks. But why does TButton have a working OnClick event if it does not have the csClickEvents attribute?